# Google Sheets Range Not Found

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to figure this out for sometime now and I just can't get it. I am trying to get a Range so that I can input a time into cell 'D4' or the next row 'D5" if 'D4' is not empty, when I click a button. I have tried all types of coding and I get "Range Not Found". I can't figure it out. What I am trying to do is click a button and input the current time into range 'D4:D10' then skip to 'D14:D20', then after 'D20' is full code a pop-up that states Click The "Clear All" button. I have the "Clear All" feature working fine and can seem to find the ranges for that function but I can't find it for this. Surely it is possible. Please Help... If I can just figure out how to input 'D4:10' range properly, I can figure out the rest.

This is what I have so far

```
function setValue(cellName, value) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).setValue(value);
}

function getValue(cellName) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).getValue();
}

function getNextRow() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("D4:D10").getLastRow + 1;
}

function addRecord(d, e,) {
  var row = getNextRow();
  setValue('D' + row, d);
  setValue('E' + row, e);
}

function btn_start() {
  addRecord(new Date());
}

function btn_stop() {
  addRecord(new Date());
}
```

[image: Range.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to know the reason of the issue of `Range Not Found`.
- You want to put the value to the next empty row in the range of `D4:D10`.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- I think that the reason of your issue of `Range Not Found` is `return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("D4:D10").getLastRow + 1;`. In this case, `getLastRow` is not used as the function. By this, such error occurs. In order to avoid this error, please modify to `return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("D4:D10").getLastRow() + 1;`. Please add `()` to `getLastRow`.
- In order to put the next empty row in the range of `D4:D10`, `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("D4:D10").getLastRow()` might not be suitable. Because in this case, the value is always put to the row `11`. I thought that this might be required to be modified.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
function getNextRow() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("D4:D10").getLastRow + 1;
}
```

- When you want to use this script, please modify to `return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("D4:D10").getLastRow() + 1;`.

To:

```
function getNextRow() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  for (var r = 4; r <= 10; r++) {
    if (sheet.getRange("D" + r).isBlank()) {
      return r;
    }
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
- [isBlank()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank)

Comment: @SoCalDiegoRob Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.